# Extracting a complicated date / time format out of a string

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am trying to find the best possible way to extract a Date and Time string that is stored in a very very strange format out of a file name (string) that was retrieved from an FTP file listing.

The string is as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 ftp      ftp        267662 Jun 06 09:13 VendorInventory_20130606_021303.txt\r
```

The specific data I am trying to extract is `20130606_021303`. `021303` is formatted as hours, seconds and milliseconds. DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ParseExact are not willing to cooperate. Any idea on how to get this up and running?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've got the entire row of the file listing, including permissions, user, owner, file size, timestamp and filename.

The data you're asking for appears to be just part of the filename.  Use some basic string manipulation (`Split`, `Substring`, etc...) first.  Then when you have just the datetime portion, you can then call `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Give it a try yourself first.  If you run into problems, update your question to show the code you are attempting, and someone will help you further.

...

Oh, fine. What the heck. I'm feeling generous.  Here's a one-liner:

```
string s = // your string as in the question

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Join(" ", s.Split('_', '.'), 1, 2),
                                  "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", null);
```

But please, next time, try something on your own first.

Comment: I didn't think of passing `null` into `ParseExact`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Passing `null` for the provider tells it to use the *current* culture.  You could pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead.  It won't matter here because there are no culture-specific items in this particular format string.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** I assume there is a fixed structure to the file display of the FTP listing, so you could simply use `String.Substring` to extract the datetime string, and then parse with `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
var s = "-rwxr-xr-x    1 ftp      ftp        267662 Jun 06 09:13 VendorInventory_20130606_021303.txt\r";
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Substring(72,15),"yyyyMMddHHmmss",null);
```

---

**Original Answer**

Use a regular expression. Try the following:

```
var s = "-rwxr-xr-x    1 ftp      ftp        267662 Jun 06 09:13 VendorInventory_20130606_021303.txt\r";

/* 
   The following pattern means:
   \d{8})    8 digits (\d), captured in a group (the parentheses) for later reference
   _          an underscore
   (\d{6})    6 digits in a group
   \.         a period. The backslash is needed because . has special meaning in regular expressions
   .*         any character (.), any number of times (*)
   \r         carriage return
   $          the end of the string
*/
var pattern = @"(\d{8})_(\d{6})\..*\r$";

var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
string dateString = matches.Groups[1].Value;
string timeString = matches.Groups[2].Value;
```

and parse using `ParseExact`:

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString + timeString,"yyyyMMddHHmmss",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
string s = "-rwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp 267662 Jun 06 09:13 VendorInventory_20130606_021303.txt\r";

// you might need to adjust the IndexOf method a bit - if the filename/string ever changes...
// or use a regex to check if there's a date in the given string 

// however - the first thing to do is extract the dateTimeString:
string dateTimeString = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("_") + 1, 15);

// and now extract the DateTime (you could also use DateTime.TryParseExact)
// this should save you the trouble of substringing and parsing loads of ints manually :)
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", null);
```